# Is it possible to find out which process initiated a MySQL restart?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

When I look at the file `/var/log/mysql/error.log` on my EC2 instance, I observe that there are two shutdowns and 2 restarts MySQL after the initial start.

```
2019-12-04T06:57:25.835650Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.D8yMDciKk5/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu)
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848479Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848493Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848499Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848503Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848537Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848834Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848841Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-12-04T06:57:25.848843Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
...
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453076Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.hkkkvHaGDX/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453235Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453247Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453251Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453255Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453285Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-12-04T06:57:28.453525Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
...
2019-12-04T06:57:30.760720Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Is there some way I can query the system (via command or some log file) to determine which process or user caused / requested these restarts?

Comment: Does querying via `journalctl -u mysqld` give you a result? Or just `systemctl status mysqld`?

Comment: The former is empty and the latter says `Unit mysqld.service could not be found.`.